# Explore the steps to create & run scheduled task

Tags: macos, mac, scheduled-tasks, automator

I am newbie to Mac OS X 10.8.

I need something like Windows Scheduler to schedule a command line program that takes parameters to run.

Can you explore the steps to schedule a task & run it at a scheduled interval.

I tried iCal to scheduled, but how to pass parameters to run.
My program require at least two parameters to run on command prompt -
java -jar myApplication.jar -arg1 -arg2 -arg3

If I schedule through iCal then how to pass those parameters.

Or can anyone suggest anything else that meet my requirement of scheduling?

Thank you in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Cronnix](http://code.google.com/p/cronnix/) to schedule tasks. It is a GUI frontend to the common UNIX [`cron`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) scheduler.

Comment: Cronnix or cron should be able to do what you need. Maybe there's something wrong with BucketCommander or your java installation. I'd start there.